# SharePoint 2013 app deployement error : Sideloading of apps is not enabled on this site

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am developing a SharePoint Hosted App through Visual Studio. It has all the default files. But when I tried to deploy the app, it shows Build Succeeded but Error in deployment.
`Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': Sideloading of apps is not enabled on this site`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The site collection should be based on "Developer Site" template or you have to enable sideloading feature if it's not, you can check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/12/10/enable-app-sideloading-in-your-non-developer-site-collection.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I found the hidden feature to enable on any site at on this post
[Enable Hidden Developer Site Feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josrod/archive/2013/02/04/quot-sideloading-of-apps-is-not-enabled-on-this-site-quot.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint On-Premise, you can give enable developer site by below power shell command

```
Enable-SPFeature e374875e-06b6-11e0-b0fa-57f5dfd72085 -url <site URL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using a "Developer Site".

I was using a "Team Site" and got the same error, but creating a new "Developer Site" solved my issue.